# Bash: How to add a string at a specific line of last second word

Tags: bash, sed

How could I use bash to add the **nouveau.modeset=0** into line starting with **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX**

Before:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

Expect:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet nouveau.modeset=0"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```

Thank you for your help.

=================================================================

Update:

Sorry for my reckless, but I have no idea how to let the **replace_word** output as **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet nouveau.modeset=0"**

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash    
replace_word=$(....)
sed '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=/c\'"$replace_word"'' filename
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us where you are stuck, we will be happy to help. I'm not the downvoter tho

Comment: @mrbolichi Update for my code, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you want to replace the string in file `file`. You can use the following:

```
sed -E "s/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"(.*)\"/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"\1 $replace_word\"/g" file
```

assuming that you previously did

```
replace_word="nouveau.modeset=0"
```

How does this work? you can see the structure of my `sed` sentence as

```
sed "s/word1/word2/g" file
```

this `s`ubstutites `word1` to `word2` in `file`, changes made `g`lobally.

`word1` in our example is `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"(.*)\"` which means capture the lines that match `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` and something quoted, The parentheses group matches that you can refer to later. So we match the quoted portion of the line. Why? to paste it along with the new text you want to add. That is what `word2` means in our example. `word2` is `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=\"\1 $replace_word\"`. `\1` means the content of the first parentheses in `word1` so it's the previous string, then you see a space and the variable you want to add. Note that I only use double quotes because simple quotes force `bash` to interpret literally the string `$replace_word` instead of evaluating it.

Note that this outputs to `STD:ERR`. If you want to save a new file, you can redirect the output **to another file** redirecting it to the same file will destroy it. If you want to save this to the same file, use `sed -i` (`i`n place)

Comment: Dear @mrbolichi, Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, without backreference:

```
$ replace_word=' nouveau.modeset=0'
$ sed '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/ s/"$/'"$replace_word"'"/' file
```

**Explanations:**

- `/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX/`: if the line matches `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`
- `s/"$/'"$replace_word"'"/'` replace ending `"` with the value of `$replace_word` followed by `"`

Comment: Dear @SLePort, Thank you for your help